# Move TR after TR in table using the ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried using multiple examples from stackoverflow but for some reason still can't get A to be show listed before B. I think I need another set of eyes.

http://jsfiddle.net/wtkqzpj2/

```
<table>
 <tr id="CATEGORY_container">
  <td>b</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<tr id="EVENTNAME_container">
 <td>a</td>
</tr>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var oobTR = $('#CATEGORY_container');
    var extTR = $('#EVENTNAME_container');

    extTR.insertAfter(oobTR);
});
```

Comment: not a valid HTML, and you are missing jQuery library

Comment: OMG. I can't believe I forgot the <table> Thank you Pranav!

Comment: Your fiddle was wrong in many ways, Here is a working one http://jsfiddle.net/2nxr3pe4/ - two tables: http://jsfiddle.net/2nxr3pe4/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle you are missing is jQuery library include it before the script. Although your markup is not valid, the [`tr` should be the child of any of these](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-contexts) : `table`, `thead`, `tfoot` or `tbody`.

If you are trying to  insert the element before the `tr` contains `a` then use [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) method instead of [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oobTR = $('#CATEGORY_container');
  var extTR = $('#EVENTNAME_container');
  extTR.insertBefore(oobTR);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="CATEGORY_container">
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr id="EVENTNAME_container">
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: O/P quoted in queston "A to be show listed before B"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edited fiddle. Basically i cloned the first row and appended it to the end of the table and then delete the first row.
    http://jsfiddle.net/wtkqzpj2/1/

```
        var oobTR = $('#ctrl_523210b6_acca_48f6_ab48_a3ffea4ce10e_CATEGORY_container').clone();
        var extTR = $('#ctrl_523210b6_acca_48f6_ab48_a3ffea4ce10e_EVENTNAME_container');
        $('#tab').append(oobTR);
$('#ctrl_523210b6_acca_48f6_ab48_a3ffea4ce10e_CATEGORY_container').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could also skip jQuery:

```js
function run(){
   var cat = document.querySelector('#categories tr');
   var evt = document.querySelector('#events tr');
   if(evt)
     cat.parentNode.insertBefore(evt,cat)
}
```

```html
<table id="categories">
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="events">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="run();">Run</button>
```